# Preventing some some elements from being `sample()`ed in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, random, tidyverse

My `for` loop below uses elements in `time_to_remove` to remove them randomly a `study`. The available elements of `time` to remove are: `2, 3, 4`.

But there is little issue. `time` elements have an order. So, after `sample()`ing for removal, we can't end up with: `time = 0,1,3` or `time = 0,1,2,4` etc. We should only end up with: `time = 0,1`, `time = 0,1,2`, `time=0,1,2,3` or `time=0,1,2,3,4`.

I wonder if such a condition can be added to my current code below?

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- expand_grid(study=1:4,group=1:2, time=0:4)

n = 1
time_to_remove <- unique(data$time)[-(1:2)]
unique_study <- unique(data$study)

for(i in time_to_remove) {
  studies_to_remove = sample(unique_study, size = n)
  time_to_remove = i
  unique_study <- setdiff(unique_study, studies_to_remove)
  data <- data %>%
    filter(
      !(   study %in% studies_to_remove &
            time %in% time_to_remove ))
}
data %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Change `time %in% time_to_remove` to `time >= time_to_remove`

Comment: @GregorThomas, thank you so much! When I run this loop many times, I never seem to see studies with only `time = 0:1` or `time=0:2`. Is there way to increase that possibility?

Comment: Delete the `[-(1:2)]` in your `time_to_remove`. Maybe keep it as `[-1]`, hard to tell for sure...

Comment: @GregorThomas, well, that is a restriction that must remain in place (we can't have a study without time 0 and 1). Because at first all studies exactly look alike, the overabundance of studies with `time=0:4` seems a bit odd.

Comment: `time_to_remove = i`  ... not a good idea to use the same name as the variable being iterated over. Instead just use `i`

Comment: @IRTFM, would you mind showing exactly how the changed line should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not an answer.  But the questioner wanted to know what the code would look like if he tried to use my comment:

```
for(i in time_to_remove) {
  studies_to_remove = sample(unique_study, size = n)
     # time_to_remove = i
  unique_study <- setdiff(unique_study, studies_to_remove)
  data <- data %>%
    filter(
      !(   study %in% studies_to_remove &
            time > i ))
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it (+1).

Comment: I also accepted this, but did have a real question: if you keep increasing `n`, there is a point at which the `sample()` call inside the `for` loop breaks throwing an error that `n` is larger than `unique_study`. To prevent this, can we internally change `n` to the nearest non-breakable number?